# How to run multiple http requests on single click in IntelliJ http file instead of running them individually

Tags: intellij-idea

I have 10 http requests in http file and want to run them on single click instead of clicking each request and see the output. Subsequent requests use output from previous requests so I want to run them serially in automated way.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment IDEA's text-based HTTP client supports variable substitution and allows to write some simple JavaScript to access response.
All you have to do is create `.http` file with all your requests defined in a sequence. Then after each request you can add JavaScript block to fill variables that next request(s) require. Example:

```
### getting json and setting variable retrieved from response body
GET http://httpbin.org/json

> {%
client.global.set("title",response.body["slideshow"]["title"])
%}

### making request using previously set variable as a body
POST http://httpbin.org/anything
Content-Type: text/plain

{{title}}
```

Next step is running all requests at once like this:

[image: run all requests]

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Run/Debug Configurations", create a few separated files and setup order in window. But you'll get a big task, you cannot wait and setup timeouts for requests.

I guess you should use [Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) for real work.

You also could try setup simple curl requests in the Linux bases os.

[image]